# knitr in command line in linux

Tags: r, linux, shell, knitr

I know the following would work in a terminal in linux to knit Rnw file into pdf, but there are simply too many lines while for Rstudio doing this only requires one click. Could someone provide a linux shell function to handle the filename as a variable?  I tryied with $1 for example, but there are "" and '' for Rscript and Rnw file name, and the shell could not recognize what is $1.

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('my_sweave_file.Rnw')"
    pdflatex my_sweave_file.tex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this. Save as a file and make sure it is runnable (i.e., use `chmod +x nameofscript`).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the first argument as variable file    
file=$1

filename=$(basename "$file")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"

Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('$file')" ; pdflatex $filename.tex
```